# Class fixture type 'SetupFixture' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments

Tags: tdd, .net-5

I created a xUnit layer in my project and tried to inject dependencies via IClassFixture but got this error

> "Class fixture type 'SetupFixture' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments"

my TestClass :

```
public class UnitTests : IClassFixture<DependencySetupFixture>
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public UnitTests(DependencySetupFixture fixture)
    {
        _serviceProvider = fixture.ServiceProvider;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_Review_Summary()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            // Arrange
            var reviewService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IxxxService>().GetEnumerator();

            // Act
            var dbtest = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();
            dbtest.Reviews.Add(new Model
            {
                ...
            });
            dbtest.SaveChanges();

            var Dto = await Service.Current.GetReviewSummary(1);

            // Arrange
            Assert.Equal(2, Dto.RecommendationPercentage);
        }
    }
}
```

My DependencySetupFixture Class :

```
public class DependencySetupFixture
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public IServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; set; }
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public DependencySetupFixture(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        ServiceCollection = serviceCollection;

        var service = IocConfig.Configure(ServiceCollection, Configuration);

        ServiceProvider = service.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

}
```

and IocConfig Class That is used in Startup too :

```
public class IocConfig
{
    public static IServiceCollection Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "myDB"));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(DbContext), typeof(Context));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IxService), typeof(xService));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IyService), typeof(yService));

        return services;
    }
}
```

I used IocConfig for inject dependencies to Startup and Test layer but got error that is not properly confided.

Comment: Yes @MarkSeemann, It was helpful. But I am carious about how can I do it with ClassFixture.

Comment: You may consider posting a new question, then.